# searching for strings with Python3

Tags: python

I'm trying to assertion the following data from this file using the following approach.

These are some of the various data that I'm trying to pull from the doc
**Cpl 
File name
Content kind
Package type
Encryption status
Container
File size
Duration
Timed text/png
Number of audio channels
2d/3d
Fps
**

```
for each_line in data:
            if 'CPL Id:' in each_line:
                cpl=(each_line.split())
            elif 'ContentTitleText:' in each_line:
                content=(each_line.split())
            elif 'Errors' in each_line:
                errors=(each_line.split())
            elif 'ContentKind' in each_line:
                contentkind=(each_line.split())
            elif 'Composition summary' in each_line:
                if 'fps' in each_line:
                    summmary=(each_line)
                    print('found comp sum',summary)
```

Here’s my file:

```
Script started on Sat 11 Jan 2014 10:57:36 AM PST
#]0;user1@ubuntu: ~#user1@ubuntu:~$ dcp_inspect /media/
 dcp_inspect v1.2013.12.16: ["/media/"]
 Image/audio analysis: Setting up temp location at /dev/shm/dcp_inspect_temp
  [...] p candidates:   0% [                    ] ETA --:--:-- Elapsed --:--:--Elapsed 00:00:00====================] ETA 00:00:00 Elapsed 00:00:00
 Found 1 Assetmap candidate: ["Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/ASSETMAP"]
 Found 11 files in total
 AM 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea: Schema check: OK: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/ASSETMAP

 Found 1 Assetmap
 AM 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/ASSETMAP
 AM 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea lists 4 assets:
 cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013_pcm.mxf
 c2cb9f04-83bf-4829-b4cf-e9963dbaa0d3: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/c2cb9f04-83bf-4829-b4cf-e9963dbaa0d3_j2c.mxf
 d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml
 edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml
 Assetmap 7599203f-a73f-4c55-b967-93c3061e10ea lists 1 PKL:
 PKL file present: edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml

 Found 1 Package
 PKL file present: edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml

 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a_pkl.xml
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: Schema check: OK
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: No Signature node found
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: AnnotationText: OVERNIGHTERS_20140108
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a lists 3 assets
 cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013: application/x-smpte-mxf;asdcpKind=Sound: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/cef846b8-8f85-4cb4-9cb8-f39e53ebe013_pcm.mxf
  [...] g hash value:   0% [                    ] ETA --:--:-- Elapsed --:--:--[=====               ] ETA 00:03:02 Elapsed 00:00:57:02:55
 c2cb9f04-83bf-4829-b4cf-e9963dbaa0d3: application/x-smpte-mxf;asdcpKind=Picture: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/c2cb9f04-83bf-4829-b4cf-e9963dbaa0d3_j2c.mxf
  [...] g hash value:   0% [                    ] ETA --:--:-- Elapsed --:--:-- g hash value:  20% [====                ] ETA 00:57:40 Elapsed 00:14:25 00:21:51 Elapsed 00:51:01
 d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: text/xml;asdcpKind=CPL: Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml
  [...] g hash value:   0% [                    ] ETA --:--:-- Elapsed --:--:--] g hash value:  16% [====                ] ETA 00:00:00 Elapsed 00:00:00A 00:00:00 Elapsed 00:00:00
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a: Package size: 93.9 GB
 PKL edc7e9bc-7397-4922-85e2-4ebf5b2d710a lists 1 composition
 CPL file present: d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml

 Found 1 Composition
 CPL file present: d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml

 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: Audio analysis ...
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: Audio analysis: Done
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Schema check: OK
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: No Signature node found
 CPL Id:           d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118
 CPL file:         /media/Overnighters_01/Interop_20140108/d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118_cpl.xml
 CPL type:         Interop (http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CPL-20040511#)
 ContentTitleText: OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV
 AnnotationText:   [Empty]
 ContentKind:      feature
 IssueDate:        2014-01-08T17:49:36-08:00 (Wednesday Jan 8 2014 17:49)
 Issuer:           Colorflow Digital
 Creator:          Colorflow
 Number of Reels:  1
 Reel 1:
 145729  01:41:12+01 @ 24.0  c2cb9f04  MainPicture  (MXF Interop, 01:43:53+18, plaintext, 1920x1080, pictures)
 145729  01:41:12+01 @ 24.0  cef846b8  MainSound    (MXF Interop, 01:43:53+18, plaintext, 6ch 48kHz 24bps, [FAIL], [FAIL], audio)
 Total duration:
 145729  01:41:12+01 @ 24.0
 CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Composition summary: "OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV", Interop, Plaintext, 2D, HD, HD, 01:41:12+01, 24.0 fps
 Composition complete

 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: MainPicture has non-DCI aspect ratio 1.778 (1920x1080, HD): Playback with proper non-standard masking recommended
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Reel 1: MainPicture has non-DCI pixel dimensions (1920x1080, HD)
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: ContentTitleText "OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV" is missing some parts
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: 9 parts matching: facility:"CLO" film_title:"OVERNIGHTERS" content_kind:"FTR" aspect_ratio:"F" audio_type:"51" resolution:"2K" studio:"EN" date:"20140108" package_type:"OV"
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: 2 parts missing: language, territory_rating
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: Part aspect_ratio claims Flat but composition aspect ratio is HD
 Hint: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Naming convention: Part resolution claims 2K but composition resolution is HD
 Info: CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Composition OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV was issued 3 days ago
 Info: dcp_inspect v1.2013.12.16 on Saturday Jan 11 2014 10:57 (00:01:18:46)
 Info: Inspected: /media
 Info: Found 1 Package with total size 93.9 GB
 Info: Found 1 Assetmap, 1 Package (0 signed), 1 Composition (0 signed, 1 plaintext/0 KDMs required)
 Info: 0 Errors, 7 Hints
#]0;user1@ubuntu: ~#user1@ubuntu:~$ exit
exit

Script done on Sat 11 Jan 2014 12:23:55 PM PST
```

And so on. But I'm not having that much luck.
For instance, on line 118 of the file, it has a bunch of info that I need.
Fps, Text type, title, 2d, runtime and so on. But how do I grab that info when I don't always
know what it will be? fps could have a different value than 24.0, 2d could be 3d in another file and so on.

I have the feeling that this isn't a big deal for people who parse text regularly.

" CPL d28cfbbd-9cc7-4cd9-ac18-66fc031b0118: Composition summary: "OVERNIGHTERS_FTR_F_EN_51_2K_20140108_CLO_OV", Interop, Plaintext, 2D, HD, HD, 01:41:12+01, 24.0 fps
"

Comment: I don't think many of us like clicking links, especially with TLD `.cz`. Can you [edit] your question to include a representative excerpt?

Comment: @mhlester the link is legit, anyway just use a regex to match lines.

Comment: Well, the string literal `'CPL Id:'` is not `in` the line you're referring to.  It looks like you're trying to express something like a regular expression, but we can't read your mind and know exactly what you do/don't want your expression to match.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I'd be surprised if it wasn't legit. I just don't like clicking links I don't know. Always better to include it in the question, no?

Comment: Well if the link dies, yes it's worth having the important bits into the question

Comment: Check this out: http://regexone.com/

Comment: added more of the things that I'm looking for.